# Can not choose button with the same name (Windows)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, appium, windows, winappdriver

### The problem

I have two buttons with the same name in Windows program. So I do:
"self.driver.find_element_by_name("button name").click()" - it selects the first one, but I need the second one.

I tried to use Inspect.exe to find AutomationId, but in the case it doesn't show AutomationId. There are name, processId etc

So how to choose the second button? Thanks!

### Environment

- Appium python client version: 0.46
- Desktop OS/version used to run Appium: Ubuntu 18.04
- Platform/version under test: Windows Server 2016
- Real device or emulator/simulator: VPS

Comment: Is there no equivalent of a find elements method - something which will return a collection of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running the click straight away you can iterate over the results and see if they are suitable before clicking them.

```
foreach (button in self.driver.find_elements_by_name("button_name"))
   if button.property == 'what i want'
       button.click()
```

You can add other constraints on the button by adjusting the if statements.
Nothing inside the foreach will run if there are no matching buttons.

Comment: It's not a python example.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_addition (__main__.SimpleCalculatorTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calculatortest.py", line 73, in test_addition
    for i in self.driver.find_element_by_name("Дополнительные отчеты и обработки"):
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

in xpath you can pass the index of the elements, for example if you want the first button to be selected give this

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath((//path to your button)[0]).click()"
```

if you want second one

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath((//path to your button)[1]).click()"
```

Please check whether index starting from 0 or 1 in your DOM

Comment: What is the language? I use python for Windows

Comment: `find_element_by_xpath()` this is python-appium function itself